# backing up certificate from keyvault

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

after a short research and documentation I've created a script based on microsoft's documentation on backing up keys and secrets and certificates.

For testing purposes I've created a self signed certificate so that I can have a certificate, created 3-4 secrets and 10 keys.

All of these scattered into two keyvaults in azure
Going through all of these with a powershell script , I have encountered an issue as follows :
"Operation "backup" is not allowed on this Key, since it is associated with a certificate. Perform the operation on the corresponding certificate. For more information refer to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/about-certificates#composition-of-a-certificate"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/about-certificates#composition-of-a-certificate%22)

Although going into that documentation and reading through the composition of a certificate, I fail to understand what exactly seems to be the issue, has anyone encountered something simillar or have experience in this field?

I will show off part of the script that is responsible for backing up the certificates, the variables are correct as all other items (secrets/keys) are being downloaded properly.

```
$certificates = az keyvault certificate list `
  --vault-name $keyVaultName `
| ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($certificate in $certificates) {
  # backup each secret
  $KeyVaultid  = $certificate.id
  $keyVaultOrder = $keyVaultid.Split("/")
  $keyVaultType = $keyVaultOrder[3]
  $certfilename = "$($certificate.name)-$keyVaultName-$keyVaultType.txt"
  az keyvault key backup `
    --vault-name $keyVaultName `
    --name $certificate.name `
    --file $certfilename
}
```

Comment: certificates are available for download using az keyvault secrets so you should be able to back them up like that

Comment: Do you want to backup Azure Key Vault certificates in the DevOps pipeline? If so, please check if you can backup successfully using scripts at you local machine. If there isn't any issue at your local machine but having issue in the pipeline, please let me know.

Comment: aside the issue with the certificate part, I managed to download locally all keys. it should be working even in a pipeline, but still didn't figure it out the cert part. looking further into it